# Breakpoint not working in Pycharm in plone project

Tags: python, debugging, ide, pycharm

When I set breakpoints in my files and run the debug, it does not stop on the breakpoints.

I am developping a plone project using pycharm (buildout, virtualenv).

The project seems well configured (Autocompletion, imports works well).

I configured my project and a the run configuration for my instance script following this https://www.fourdigits.nl/blog/pycharm3-and-plone

Does pycharm allow me to debug this king of project?

Comment: Check pycharm-debug.egg file. When I update pycharm breakpoints not stopped. Then I check pycharm-debug.egg and this file had been updated too. Now I use the new pycharm-debug.egg and breakpoints work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I updated pycharm, I have an error when I try to debug in python 2.4, and it works well with another version. I close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Also check the path to your project/script. It looks like PyCharm debugger can't work with non-english letters in the path (for example with umlauts and Russian letters).